# Format comments in vim starting with #' (hash-dash)

Tags: python, r, vim, format, comments

Using vim, I am using gw or gwap to automatically format long comments in python or R, and vim inserts #-signs automatically at the beginning of the line where needed. Both in python and R, comments for automatic documentation generation start with #' instead of #, and vim has no idea on how to handle those.

How to teach vim that lines with #' are comments, too, and when formatting the line into a block to add #'-signs to the beginning of each line?

Minimal example:

```
#' Some random text. Please
#' format me 
#' nicely by
#' typing gwap anywhere in this paragraph.
```

Should become something like:

```
#' Some random text. Please format me 
#' nicely by typing gwap anywhere in
#' this paragraph.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expand the [`comments` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27comments%27):

```
'comments' 'com'        string  (default
                                "s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,b:#,:%,:XCOMM,n:>,fb:-")
                        local to buffer
                        {not in Vi}
                        {not available when compiled without the |+comments|
                        feature}
        A comma separated list of strings that can start a comment line.  See
        |format-comments|.  See |option-backslash| about using backslashes to
        insert a space.
```

Formatting uses this option to recognise comment leaders. Each comma-separated entry is of the form `{flags}:{string}`, where flags control what type of comment formatting is used.

Add `b:#'` to that list to have text formatting insert matching comment leaders, `b` stands for *blank required*, so only `#'` followed by some whitespace, then text, is seen as a comment leader:

```
:set comments+=b:#'
```

See [`:help format-comments`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#format-comments) for more information.

Demo:

[image: comment formatting with additional <code>comments</code> setting]

Take into account that a [filetype plugin](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html) can override the `comments` option again; you can add the same setting as an override (with a [`:setlocal` command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%3Asetlocal)) in the respective `~/.vim/ftplugin/<type>.vim` file (create it if it doesn't exist yet).

So for a Python buffer, if there is a `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` file it'll be run after the general `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim` file has been executed letting you set additional configuration for this filetype, including the extra comment configuration.

Comment: It seems that this is only working if 'filetype=' but whenever the filetype is set to anything specific (say =python), it does not work any more. Was I to quick to accept the answer? Do I miss something?

Comment: @ThomasMöbius: your python type definition may be re-setting the `comments` option. Let me troll through the docs to see how you can augment that definition in that case.

Comment: @ThomasMöbius: I've added instructions on how to update a local (filetype specific) comments option, with links to the documentation.

Comment: You are officially awesome.